# Jquery validate remote after error and submit Handler with ajax and datatype json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, validation

I turn arround with my problem and search everywhere how to fix it.

The context : Jquery | validate plugin | remote rule  => check if email already  exist.

MY BUG : after a remote check and email good to go => return '1'  true , I submit and do my ajax stuff , the json response is with a 1 in front like that : **1{"response":"success","msg":"good"},**

I'm sure this '1' come from the remote rule for the email (I tried without the remote rule and it works fine) , my problem I don't know how to clear this value to have a clear json value. so here is  my javascript .

```
$(document).ready(function()    {





 function jq_msg(data, scrollTopValue, TimeoutValue)    {
        $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: scrollTopValue},"slow");
        $("#jq_msg").html(data.msg).slideDown("slow");
        if(TimeoutValue > 0) {
            setTimeout("$(\"#jq_msg\").slideUp(\"slow\")", TimeoutValue);
        }
    }



 $("#form").validate({

  submitHandler: function(form) {

                    $.ajax({
                url:        "welcome/signup",
                cache:      false,
                type:       "post",
                data:       $("#form").serialize(),
                dataType:   "json",
                success:    function(data)  {
                    jq_msg(data,70,0);
                    if(data.response == "success") {
                        /*setTimeout("window.location = http://kit.xubraz.com/about", 3000);*/
                        $("#form").hide("explode",{pieces:13},1000);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#email").effect("shake",null,"fast");
                    }
                }

            });


  },


  rules: {  
  email: {required:true,email: true,remote:{url:"welcome/checkuserexist",type:"post"}},
  password: {required:true,minlength:5},
  passconf: {required:true,minlength:5,equalTo:'#password'},
  },

  messages: {
  email: {required:"Email address required",email: "Valid email address required",remote: "This email already exist,You already have an account"},  
  password: {required: "Password required",minlength:"min 10 caracters"},  
  passconf: {equired:"retype your password",minlength:"min 10 caracters",equalTo:'this password confirmation is different'},

  },



  });








});
```

Comment: Where did `{"response":"success","msg":"good"}` come from?

Comment: What about your server-side code; i.e. `welcome/checkuserexist`? If the remote check is disabled, then it's probably your server-side code; e.g. a stray print() or echo() somewhere?

Comment: he message come from the server after a submit and a valid form , I return => json_encode(array('response'=>'success','msg' => 'good' )); on the welcome/checkuserexist => I return an echo TRUE or FALSE , that's it –

Comment: Ok , my apologize, my bad , I'm working with codeigniter and in my form_validation.php array in the rules I did a callback so the callback send a true/false value this is the value I get all the time when it's true(1). So I found out ... sorry for your time again.